# Beizer circle messes up model

Tags: bezier-curves

I am new to using blender, and found something I wasn't able to solve.

---

I have a simple model like this:

[image]

With texture from the bottom:

[image]

I would like to curve this model like a bracelet, did it with a **beizer circle** + **curve modifier**.

But somehow it messes up my model, as you see here:

[image]

What could I do? I tried changing the resolution but not much has happened..

Comment: First make sure that you have applied rotation to the object (ctrl+A). Then keep in mind that the deformation occurs along the Z axis ob the object, but along the the Y axis on the curve.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your 1st picture, your Curve is overlapping each other.

So your 3rd picture looks like having a double faces.

Better still, instead of using Bezier Curve + Curve Modifier, use your Bezier Curve to get the kind of Curve you are expecting from Curve Modifier and then Extrude.

After Extrude, you can do the thickness.